# jQuery script: edit <p> tag on click and save on Enter

Tags: jquery

I have the following objective. Let's say I have `<p>` tag:

```
<p class="editbox">Original text</p>
```

I want to make a small jQuery script, which will replace `<p>` tag with `<textarea>` for user to input text, and when user hits Enter,  dissapears and user's text inserts in `<p>` tag.

For example:

1. I have `"Original text"` string in `<p>` tag.
2. I click on this string and `<textarea>` appears with `"Original text"`
   inside.
3. I write `"Original text is updated"`.
4. I hit `Enter`.
5. `<textarea>` dissapears.
6. `<p>` tag appears again.
7. `<p>` tag is `"Original text is updated"` now.

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: [Here's a quick fiddle of what you want](http://jsfiddle.net/h5yk0h73/1/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `contentEditable` attribute, it will (magicly) make your `p` tag editable :)

```
<p contentEditable="true">I'm editable :)</p>
```

This is HTML5

Source : [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_Editable)

Comment: This is much nicer than a textarea showing up, IMHO

Answer (score 3):

Please check this code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('p').click(function() {
    $('p').hide();
    $('textarea').show();
  });

  $("textarea").keypress(function(event) {
    if (event.which == 13) {
      $('p').show().html($('textarea').val());
      $('textarea').hide();
    }
  });
})
```

```css
textarea {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>

<p class="editbox">Original text</p>
<textarea>Original text</textarea>
```